# Unable to trigger checkbox change

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3. and I want to trigger each checkbox state change.

This code is working when I put it inside the click event:

```
$("#btn_off").click(function(){
   $( "tr td input" ).each(function( index ) 
   {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       //some code
    }
   });
});
```

but when I use this code it's not:

```
$('tr td input').live('change', function(){ 
    if(this.checked)
    {
       //something
    }
});
```

then I have tried with:

```
$('tr td input').on('change', function(){ 
    if(this.checked)
    {
       //something
    }
});
```

and with the following:

```
$('tr td :checkbox').change(function() { 
    if(this.checked)
    {
       //something
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? This code is located in the `.ready()`
This is the only checkbox on the website so I'm sure that `selector` should work...

Comment: I think you should use $(this).is(":checked") for the last three cases as well, instead of this.checked

Comment: @JonasGrumann i don't think so

Comment: can you share your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `click` event:

```
$('tr td input').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to use $(this).is(':checked') instead of this.checked

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr td input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            alert('checked');
        else
            alert('not checked');
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nuxbox/vxyHq/

Comment: I know that this should work but it's not...nothing is being triggered.

Comment: you mean you don't see the alert popping up?

Comment: can you post more codes? maybe somewhere on your javascript is giving errors and therefore causing the alert no to trigger

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?: http://jsfiddle.net/msapD/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr td input').change(function() { 
        if(this.checked)
        {
           alert("Checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The jsfiddle I posed works with what I posed.
Then there must be some sort of format issue or conflict.  Can you put your work in a jsfiddle?  I wouldn't mind looking it over.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').delegate('td input:checkbox','click',function() { 
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
           alert("Checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with property checked

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
        alert('checked');
    else
        alert('unchecked');
});
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/zHyKB/)

Comment: Also check if you using On the jquery version should be 1.7 or higher, as live is deprecated from 1.7